# Create a Docker container with MySQL/MariaDB database

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I'm planning to migrate my application stack to Docker. Let me describe the services I'm currently using:

- **HAProxy**, which is used for SSL termination on all service's connections (HTTP and raw TCP connections), and forwards traffic to the services below.
- **Nginx**, which serves static files, like updates and some information pages.
- **Node.js**, which runs the main applications.
- **MySQL (MariaDB)**, the database used and shared by all the applications.

My question is about the database.

What's the proper way of running MariaDB in this case?

1. Install and run it inside my container, along with the other services?
2. Run the [official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/) in a separate container, and link my container to it with the `--link` option of Docker's `run` command?

Does the first option have any disadvantage?

[TeamSpeak docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/solidnerd/teamspeak/) uses the second option and that's what made me question myself about the correct way of running the database in my case, but I particularly feel more inclined to package all the services inside my own image.

Comment: Please look at `docker-compose` which would fit your case.

Comment: Please explain why Docker is an advantage for any of the stack.  (I'm not arguing against Docker, but rather hoping to derive an answer that addresses your needs.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker Philosophy: Split your application into `microservices` and use a container for each `microservice`.

In your case, I recommend  a `MariaDB` container, Using official (`Library`) Image gives you easier update management, but feel free to use your custom image.

An `HAProxy` Container, A `nginx` container and a `nodejs` container.

This way you divided your application into `microservices`, and you can upgrade, manage and  troubleshoot them easier in an isolated environment.

If you are thinking about delivering your application to end users via docker, a simple `docker-compose` file will do the trick for easy launching the required containers.